# Custom ExceptionMapper not working in Spring + Jersey + Jetty

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

My exception mapper looks like below

```
@Provider
public class DAExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DAException> {
    @Override
    public @ResponseBody Response toResponse(DAException exception) {
    }
}

public class DAException extends Exception {
}
```

I'm using Spring 3.2.5 with Jersey 2.15 on Jetty 8.1.14.

I'm can't find why my exception mapper is not getting registered with Spring. I get 500 when I throw a custom DAException in my application. I tried all solutions in https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2063. None of them worked.

I currently don't have any beans for exception registered in spring context xml. My application doesn't set resources through program.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is DAException [responseStatus=Unauthorized, errorMessage=ErrorMessage [errorMessage=User is not allowed to access this resource.], errorDescription=User is not allowed to access this resource.]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
```

Comment: Try and make `DAException` extend `WebApplicationException`

Comment: @peeskillet, May work but I really want to use interface option than extending.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the toResponse method?

```
@Provider
public class DAExceptionMapper implements
        ExceptionMapper<DAException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(DAException ex) {
        return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain")
                .build();
    }
}
```

There's also this but it sounds like this is related to jersey versions > 2.5 [toResponse in jersey ExceptionMapper does not get invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413239/toresponse-in-jersey-exceptionmapper-does-not-get-invoked)

Comment: Sorry for not updating complete class. But I had toResponse in my class. Also, I tried all solutions in the page link you provided. Adding Singleton or Service annotation also did not work.