# Javax Exception Mapper just throws 500

Tags: java, rest, exception, jax-rs, exceptionmapper

I have a REST interface implemented with javax to login a user.

```
@Path("/login")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UserId login(@QueryParam("email") String email, @QueryParam("password") String password) throws InvalidUserDataException {
    User user;
    try {
        user = loadUserFromDatabase(null, email);
    } catch (MissingDatabaseEntryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw  new InvalidUserDataException("Email and password do not match.");
    }
    if(!user.confirmed)
        throw new InvalidUserDataException("We have sent you a confirmation mail. Please confirm your email first.");
    if(!user.password.equals(password))
        throw  new InvalidUserDataException("Email and password do not match.");

    return new UserId(user.userId);
}
```

Furthermore there is an `Exception Mapper` to map the thrown exceptions to the specific HTTP response.

```
@Provider
public class InvalidUserDataExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<InvalidUserDataException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(InvalidUserDataException exception)
    {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

No matter what error I am throwing and what status code I am defining in mapper class, the server always responds just with an 500 Internal Server Error instead with the defined 409. Does anybod know what I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the mapper being called?

Comment: where should it be called?

Comment: Is the `toResponse()` method called? Jersey should call it when the exception is thrown. Set a breakpoint or println to check.

Comment: no it is not called, but I don't no why

Comment: Because it's not registered. How are you configuring your app? Is it with an web.xml? If so, can you post it.

Comment: Check out some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22413239/2587435). Find the one that is specific to your app configuration.

Comment: had to add the class to the deployment agnostic application model.

Comment: I have the same problem. I confirm that my ExceptionMapper is fired as expected, but any status code is replaced by 500.